# GET_STRING in simple asm Assembly doesn't return string

Tags: assembly, sasm

I am new to assembly and trying to do a small excersise for the classroom.

Collecting 3 input variables from user:

- 1st one is a math operation symbol ( + - and *)
- 2nd variable is a number to add or substract from other number (3rd variable)

example 1: User should input in-order: +, 4, and 5 and gets 9

example 2: user types -, 9, 5 should get 4

I'm not able to compare the math operator as a string, so it is being stuck at the addition problem.. it only adds the numbers even if changed the symbol to minus.

tried changing the GET_STRING to GET_DEC and made numbers act as math symbols, it worked, so I think it is a syntax issue I'm not able to figure out how to check/validate the GET_STRING input or how to compare it exactly with the logic

I am using simple sasm IDE/editor

Here is my code  appreciate your help in advance

```
%include "io.inc"
section .data
section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging

 GET_STRING [operation],8 // here I treid everything, even GET_CHAR didn't work
 GET_DEC 4,[firstVar]
 GET_DEC 4,[secondVar]

mov eax,[operation]
cmp eax, opAdd
 je Addit
jne L2

L2: 
mov eax,[operation]
cmp eax, opSub
je Subbit
jne L3

L3: 
mov eax,[operation]
cmp eax, "*"
 je Multit

Addit:
mov eax,[firstVar]
mov ebx,[secondVar]
add eax,ebx 
jmp PRINT


Subbit:
mov eax,[firstVar]
mov ebx,[secondVar]
sub eax,ebx
jmp PRINT

Multit:
mov eax,[firstVar]
mov ebx,[secondVar]
mul ebx
jmp PRINT

PRINT:
PRINT_DEC 4,eax

 xor eax, eax
 ret
```

Comment: Have you tried running this under the debugger?  What's in `eax` right before you do `cmp eax, opAdd`?  Also, where are the declarations for your variables?

Comment: Also, you need to ponder this statement: `mov eax,[operation]`  EAX can hold 32 bits worth of information (aka 4 bytes or characters).  Using `mov` like that will load all 32 bits from the memory location.  But will the 4 bytes at `operation` be exactly `opAdd`?  Perhaps you should only read 1 byte from `operation`?